# Adding login form to nav menu

Tags: html, forms, css, navbar

I have a simple header and nav bar in my page. I want to add username/password and Login button to the nav bar but I wasn't able to do it. Every time I add the code it is not in the nav bar, either below the bar or above the bar. Can anyone help?

Here is the JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ds7ezkn8/2/

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="languages.html">Programming Languages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="languages.html">Which Language?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="htmlcss.html">HTML &#38; CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="java.html">Java</a></li>
                    <li><a href="python.html">Python</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Join The Club</a></li>
            <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>   

        </ul>



    </nav>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have given 25% of each

, because od which if you add new text field it won't wrap inside nav

I have updated the fiddle, please look into it

https://jsfiddle.net/ds7ezkn8/2/

I have reduced the width of li

```
nav li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}
```

Is this your expectation?

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that :)